# How can I remove animate of the header when I move the next screen?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using react-navigation. I set headerBackground of the option because I want to achieve gradient of the header. But it will appear white of flicker when I move the next screen, I guess this is the reason for the animation. I am trying to configuration transitionConfig but it not work. This is my navigationOptions:

```
headerBackground: (
      <Image
        style={{height: setHeight(58), width: setWidth(375), resizeMode: 'stretch'}}
        source={require('./assets/images/top-bg.jpg')}
      />
),
transitionConfig: () => ({
    screenInterpolator: StackViewStyleInterpolator.forHorizontal,
    transitionSpec: {
      duration: 0,
      timing: Animated.timing,
      easing: Easing.step0
    }
})
```

[enter link view renderings here](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/29296597/57428495-3cd9ae00-725b-11e9-90be-ae1d8bc9d914.gif)

How can I remove animate of the header when I move the next screen? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All animations are handled in CSS, and it seems like the stackViewStyleInterpolator.forHorizontal is the tag responsible here. I would look in my CSS for something that resembles that, or use the inspector to tell you where exactly that element is being acted upon and then edit the CSS directly.